# Wifi usb dongle ignores drivers/modules after reboot

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb, drivers, authentication

I seem to have stuck. Problem is while using the wifi USB dongle from Dlink.

This is the wifi dongle for which we are talking here:

product link

I bought a new piece and did some research on how to install the drivers of this on linux. To my surprise, the time I plugged this usb dongle, it started to work and showed me the wifi connections available.

Great, it is working as expected.

However, whenever I restart the machine, it does not work. And then I had to take it out and plug that in to make it work. Bottom line is: It does not work by default on boot up/restart but works if I plug out/plug in after boot up.

Strange. Later I started doing some research and came across an article that I would have to disable the secure boot options. Alas, I could not find any secure boot options in bios menu.

I researched more and found that I would have to add the by default to be loaded modules into /etc/modules. Something like this:

```
sudo -i
echo 8192eu >> /etc/modules
exit
```

OR

Activate the wlan by:

```
sudo modprobe -r 8192eu
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

8192eu being the wlan name.

Unfortunately, this also did not work. Are there any experts to help out on this for guidance?

This is what I see as output of lsusb

.... Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2001:3319 D-Link Corp. ....

And this is what I see in dmesg

[ 9.643176] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-300:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-300:00, irq=MAC)

[ 9.839438] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down [ 9.887172] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-900:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-900:00, irq=MAC)

[ 10.063362] r8169 0000:09:00.0 enp9s0: Link is Down

[ 11.003516] loop14: detected capacity change from 0 to 8

[ 11.458195] wlx085a11027f20: authenticate with 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46

[ 11.476862] wlx085a11027f20: send auth to 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46 (try 1/3)

[ 11.679229] wlx085a11027f20: send auth to 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46 (try 2/3)

[ 11.883169] wlx085a11027f20: send auth to 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46 (try 3/3)

[ 12.091330] wlx085a11027f20: authentication with 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46 timed out

[ 13.261560] wlx085a11027f20: authenticate with 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46

[ 13.273232] wlx085a11027f20: send auth to 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46 (try 1/3)

[ 13.475691] wlx085a11027f20: send auth to 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46 (try 2/3)

[ 13.679292] wlx085a11027f20: send auth to 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46 (try 3/3)

[ 13.887159] wlx085a11027f20: authentication with 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46 timed out

[ 15.464480] wlx085a11027f20: authenticate with 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46 [ 15.476314] wlx085a11027f20: send auth to 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46 (try 1/3)

[ 15.663447] rfkill: input handler disabled [ 15.679167] wlx085a11027f20: send auth to 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46 (try 2/3)

[ 15.883163] wlx085a11027f20: send auth to 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46 (try 3/3)

[ 16.087144] wlx085a11027f20: authentication with 30:cc:21:ea:a9:46 timed out

And it keeps going on and on.